# Toast not getting finished after pressing back button on android device?

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast, android-app-licensing

I am developing a paid app, which checks for the license upon starting (from `onCreate()` method)  the app. After receiving the response codes from server, the subsequent callback methods `allow()`, `dontAllow()`, `applicationError()` executes which contains different `Toasts`.

Now my question is that whenever any `Toasts` gets generated and if suddenly I press device's back `Button` before the finishing off the `Toast` then the `Toast` gets stuck on the screen. It gets finished off only when I remove the app from task list.

```
 private class XYZLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {

    @Override
    public void allow(int reason) {
        if(isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(XyzActivity.this,"App purchase verified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("allowed called"+reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void dontAllow(int reason) {
        if(isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        displayResult(String.valueOf(reason));
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(XyzActivity.this,"App not licensed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("don't allow called"+reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
        if(isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(XyzActivity2108.this,"Not able to verify the license,check your internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // finish();
        System.out.println("app error called"+errorCode);
    }
}
```

Here is my `onBackpressed()` method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Any help from your side please?

Comment: Try this: Toast.makeText(XyzActivity.this, text, 200).show(); instead of LENTH.SHORT

Comment: tried, doesn't worked

Comment: are you running this code inside a Service or IntentService?

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable `Toast toast;`

To show it use

```
toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Then on back press cancel the toast.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    toast.cancel();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why not use snackbar instead?**
This is your app message, not a system message.

> Your toast remains on screen even when the activity is finished. Snackbar doesn't.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34432504/8127390) from stackoverflow for more details.

---

Even if you don't want to use snackbar. This doesn't seem an expected behaviour from your code. What might be causing the problem is the **long running thread** that is still connected with the server, or has **not finished yet**. Check that the code triggering this(XYZLicenseCheckerCallback) is executing properly and is not making the app not responding.

**Note**: You must take extra considerations while interacting with the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

pass context in constructor and Toast with this context

```
 private class XYZLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
 Activity mActivity;
 public XYZLicenseCheckerCallback (Activity mActivity){
 this.mActivity= mActivity;
 }
@Override
public void allow(int reason) {
    if(isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(mActivity,"App purchase verified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("allowed called"+reason);
}

@Override
public void dontAllow(int reason) {
    if(isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    displayResult(String.valueOf(reason));
    stopService(serviceIntent);
    Toast.makeText(mActivity,"App not licensed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("don't allow called"+reason);
}

@Override
public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
    if(isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(mActivity,"Not able to verify the license,check your internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // finish();
    System.out.println("app error called"+errorCode);
 }
 }
```